# Is it safe to waste time when there is no timed quest or active threat?

Tags: pathfinder-kingmaker

The first main quest has a 3 month time limit. And reading about the concept of the kingdom management after that part starts, there will be periodical crises which have to be solved else the game is lost.

However, when there is no timed quest and when there is no active threat at the moment, is it safe to waste time? Or is there a global hidden time limit which can cause trouble?

And, more specifically, if I manage to defeat the first quest a lot sooner than the time limit, for example in one month, will I suffer any negative consequences for wasting the other two months just wandering around before reporting it as completed? Are there events which progress during that time?